# My facebook like counter always reset to zero

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I've installed Facebook like counter in each article of my webpage. The question is probably the same as [This Thread](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6369675/facebook-like-button-counter-suddenly-vanished-why). Unfortunately, my like counter keep vanishing so often, for example, if you guys look into [this page](http://www.mevblog.com), all of the counters in the first page were not in zero (Most of them are 10++ like). I captured my web display last Sat to compare with today in [this link](http://www.screencast.com/t/djdyqKsGm955).I have no idea at all. Actually, the code I've used is just below in each article together with meta tag

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" 
                lang="en" dir="ltr">

<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mevblog.com%2Fmev%2Fnode%2F780&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=60" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:60px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because of the og tags on that page.

http://www.mevblog.com/mev/node/780

vs

http://www.mevblog.com/mev/play-learn-plearn-museum-siam

See: http://graph.facebook.com/10150777694150224

And see: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mevblog.com%2Fmev%2Fnode%2F780

If you change your url iframe to be the canonical one, does it work better?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the comment. I have tried as your suggestion (adding opengraph info) but the facebook like counters are still reset to zero from time to time. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: They can reset to 0 when all the people unlike your link.  That's the only way it can reset to 0 (other than for if the URL is not publicly accessible to Facebooks linter tool).

Comment: As in my history, I and my friends still 'Like' on that link (posted in my wall) but the counter appears zero.

Comment: This is what I see on your page:  50 people like this. Be the first of your friends.