# Facebook like counter always zero and facebook comments disapearing

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-like

I have some problem with the Facebook plugins in the site: www.talnavarro.com

In some posts the like button counter always stays on zero, but there are some posts that the counter works just fine.
I've tried to disable all the social plugins in my site (maybe some conflict between them) and put simple Facebook like code from the Facebook developers site, and still the counter didn't work.

another problem is that my Facebook comments sometimes disappear...

So basely, what that i need is someone that will fix my social plugins in my site..

Thank you

Comment: show us that your plugin not working?? i visited the website i saw everything fine..

Comment: try to like this post
http://www.talnavarro.com/2012/05/31/maldives-islands-diving-part-4/
and refresh...
you'll see the counter remains on zero

Comment: @guyklainer we're facing the same problem - did you find any solution? there is also a similar bug reported on FB - http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/360970683958438

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988170/my-facebook-like-counter-always-reset-to-zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=210086019031867 there are 6 meta tags that your page should have. Debug your page url with the linter tool (
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and check that the debug tool read ALL the required meta tags. In my case I missed the fb:app_id and og:site_name (looks like fb became more strict about it because it used to work without it).

Comment: so i tried to add the "og:image:url" and the debugger steel giving me the same error : 
Object at URL 'http://www.talnavarro.com/2012/05/31/maldives-islands-diving-part-4/' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value '' for property 'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.

and the like button is steel on zero...

Comment: you still miss the fb:app_id meta tag - this one is very imporatnant (though the debugger don't tell you about it). Also, specify a relevant image or some default image you can use.

Comment: just add an image url to the content of the og:image tag

Comment: i did it and it didnt help so i removed it

Comment: If you'll post your code it would be helpful, remember - you have to have fb:app_id + linter tool should show no errors. For that purpose you should set some default image url to the og:image tag.

Comment: <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.talnavarro.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/11570_191933036942_750621942_3155127_5435615_n-e1331071367490.jpg"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="329346423775877" />

Comment: this is the 2 meta tags that i've added and still the same error

Comment: look at the error you get in the facebook debug tool with your page url (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.talnavarro.com%2F2012%2F05%2F31%2Fmaldives-islands-diving-part-4%2F), I think you might want to change your og:type to "blog" instead of "website"

Comment: I suddenly faced [the same problem](http://support.addthis.com/customer/en/portal/questions/629847-facebook-counter-always-zero-can-t-like-opengraph-correct-) without changing any code, and the OpenGraph linter shows all tags are correct. I'm using AddThis, which is the likely culprit.

Comment: *UPDATE*: it's not AddThis. [Facebook recently performed some obscure migration of their like plugin, and in the process broke it - you can no longer point the like href to a Facebook page. It has to be your web page's URL.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13372704/1269037)